Change the color of line based on condition in Grafana
I have a dataset like this:
+------------------+----------+------------------+------------------+
|         metric   |      date|      upper_limit |    lower_limit   |
+------------------+----------+------------------+------------------+
|0.8629607598562075|2023-01-01|0.8772620759744124|0.7937133068339922|
|0.8605378508401539|2023-02-01|0.9032219546299174|0.8172008160937347|
|0.8093681029562033|2023-03-01|0.9279615008449871|0.8395842150502264|
| 0.701702766685897|2023-04-01|0.9267865892517674| 0.838521199799218|
|0.6764983358418296|2023-05-01| 0.922840322393428|0.8349507678797682|
|0.6698944854298756|2023-06-01|0.9217385543537551| 0.833953930129588|

I am storing this data in graphite and then populating a dashboard in graphana.
I want to have a rule when  metric > upper_limit or metric < lower_limit change the color of the metric line . How do I do that ?

To do conditional formatting in Grafana based on the cell value, you need to do the following:

Make sure your Field type is numeric
Add an Override rule and select yout Field by its name
Set Cell options > Cell type to Colored background
Click Add override property and pick Thresholds
Add as many threshold rules as you want, and click the colored circles to pick your desired color.

It works like this: cells will be the color of Base, unless they exceed the value of a threshold, then it will be the color of the highest threshold it exceeded.
If you want color only for values within a range, have your no color (transparent) on Base,
your desired color on the first threshold, and No color again in your second threshold.


This doesn't really answer question asked, is it? Through override you can only set constant threshold for all rows. But data provided by OP implement that they want threshold to be per-row.

hmm, I see. Yep, in that case it seems to exceed the built-in capacities of Grafana. Probably a plugin would be the way to go.

My personal preferred way to go in situation like this is to create an additional column on the data source side, and color based on it. But I lack knowledge in graphite to say how (or even if) this can be done.

@markalex I can add an addition column (like a flag) in graphite but after that how do I change the color based on the flag value ? Like say 0 would have green and 1 would have red in color coding

@AyanBiswas, exactly how Rodrigo described in this answer. And if the part you are specifically interested in is colouring whole row, in Grafana 11 they added "Apply to entire row" option to Cell options > Cell type (Colored background) > Apply to entire row

@markalex In my grafana 11, the option "apply to entire row" is not showing. There's any way to enable it?

@PedroRibeiro, AFAIK, it should be. Check this if what you are attempting is correct.

That's what I have configured. The cell has background color, but I want to apply to the row. But there's no "Apply to entire row" switch available. Maybe I just need to configure something on the ini file, but I couldn't found anything online regarding this.
